# How to make a text field always be the size of the window. Python

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I make a text field always be the size of the window. Here is the rest of the code I tryed what you posted by itself and it worked but it wont work here.

here is what I have but it does not work.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from tkMessageBox import *
from tkColorChooser import askcolor
import re

class Application(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.pack()
    self.Saved = None
    self.FontColor = "Black"
    self.BackgroundColor = "White"
    self.FontSize = IntVar()
    self.Check = None
    self.Create_Widgets()

def Create_Widgets(self):
    menubar = Menu(root)

    FileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    FileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.New)
    FileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.Save)
    FileMenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=self.SaveAs)
    FileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.Open)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=FileMenu)

    FormatMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    FormatMenu.add_command(label="Font Color", command=self.TextCC)
    FormatMenu.add_command(label="Background Color", command=self.BackgroundCC)
    FormatMenu.add_command(label="Font Size", command=self.ChangeFontSize)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=FormatMenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)

    self.Cont = Text(self,wrap=WORD)
    self.Cont.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
```

Comment: What GUI do you use - PyQt, PySide, wxPython, Tkinter ?

Comment: @furas I am using Tkinter.

Comment: So why did you set `width` and `height` if you want to resize it.

Comment: @furas even when I don't set width and height it does not work.

Comment: It is my old example with `Button` but I didn't check it with `Text`
http://blog.furas.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/tkinter-pack.png http://blog.furas.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/tkinter-grid.png

Comment: @furas It does not work.

Comment: @furas Do I have to have the widget in a frame  by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this code and `Text` is resized to window size - even if I change window size.

```
from Tkinter import *

self = Tk()

Cont = Text(self,width=110,height=30,wrap=WORD)
Cont.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=YES)

self.pack()


self.mainloop()
```

So maybe there is another problem.

---

**EDIT:**

`Application` is a `Frame` inside window created automaticly by Tkinter.
You have to resize that frame too

```
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
```

Comment: Thank you you have been very helpful with solving some problems I have been having while making this program.

Comment: You code look clean so it is easer to find element and test it. Only one thing: there is the rule - names of variables, function, class instances in lowercase (and with `_`). Uppercase should be reserved for class names - event StackOverflow use the same color in your code for class names and variables because it treats both as class names.